# Efficiency of logging in PHP?

Tags: php, performance, logging

I'm working on a PHP/CodeIgniter web app that will be the backend for a non-realtime game. We want the ability to record game activity for later analysis. In my performance tests using either codeigniter's own logging system or log4php, file logging seems slow, reducing the number of requests per second the server can handle by 50%. I've tried it on both a WAMP machine and an Apache/Ubuntu server. If I change logging to use MongoDB, the performance only drops by a few percent, even if I'm logging the same amount of information.

Is file logging going to be inherently slow for php scripts because they are all waiting on locks on the same file or is it likely a configuration issue?

Comment: I am a little surprised that performanced *dropped* when you switched to MongoDB. The only way files are going to be any faster is if you just append to them. But what are you going to do with these logs? It might be better to just use a database.

Comment: Remember that how much you're logging can be as important as how you log it.  If you haven't already, consider thinning down the verbosity of your log information.  It may even be worth it to use action IDs and decode them later.

Comment: What are you logging and how big is it? I would find it hard to believe that it would kill r/s by 50%... Can you not use error_log and specify a destination log file? You really can't get much faster than the sapi functions.

Comment: @null: Sorry, I mean that performance in mongo dropped by only a few percent relative to no logging at all. So if no logging = 100 r/s,  mongo = 95 r/s, log4php log to file = 50 r/s.

Answer (score 0):

You can try logging in RAM drive file(s). 
Also consider naming of the logs by a date stamp like YYYY-mm-dd-HH.log so you can periodically take older logs and process (archive) them and the drive will stay clean.